# Updating taxonomy vocabularies with Rules?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, rules, actions

I'm wondering if there's a way to add/edit/delete Taxonomy terms in a Rule with Drupal 7? I haven't found any way to define an action that will let me do that.

Usecase: I'm trying to use Rules to maintain a vocabulary of usernames of a certain role, so when a user's role is updated I add/remove their username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the rules action "Set data value."  If the user includes a taxonomy reference field, you should be able to add or remove it this way.

Alternatives:
I'm not sure what you intend to use the vocabulary of usernames for, but it is straightforward to use the views module to generate a list of users by role.

Alternately, I have been using the flag module-- the latest Drupal 7 beta features rules integration-- to automatically flag users upon adding or removing roles.  You may be able to use flags instead of a vocabulary.

Comment: That worked, thanks! However I'm still curious as to the editing/deleting taxonomy terms, as that would be useful in number of other circumstances.